# Change .Net Array bounds

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I pass data from one third-party lib to another one.

Given an `object[,]` with lower bounds `{0,0}`, I need to make `object[,]` with lower bounds `{1,1}`.

Is there a way to perform this convertion without creating new array and copying all the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to perform this convertion without creating new array and copying all the data?

No. You can't change the size or bounds of an array once it has been created.

Comment: what about the array.resize  under the hood is creating a new array no  ?

Comment: @K.B: Yes, that creates a new array and copies the data - it doesn't modify the existing array object.

Comment: @K.B. Quote from the documentation of Array.Resize: `This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one. array must be a one-dimensional array. `

Comment: @Heinzi thanks  I have decompiled it and it's look  like this

Comment: public static void Resize<T>(ref T[] array, int newSize)
    {
      if (newSize < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("newSize", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
      T[] objArray1 = array;
      if (objArray1 == null)
      {
        array = new T[newSize];
      }
      else
      {
        if (objArray1.Length == newSize)
          return;
        T[] objArray2 = new T[newSize];
        Array.Copy((Array) objArray1, 0, (Array) objArray2, 0, objArray1.Length > newSize ? newSize : objArray1.Length);
        array = objArray2;
      }
    }

Comment: @K.B: No need to decompile .NET source. Just go look at it online: http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/

Comment: @JimMischel thanks but is more fast to do this with Resharper